# What is that green bug icon in Pyscripter?

Tags: python, ide

It seems to appear after I've worked on a file for a little while in a session.  I can't find it on Google, probably since I'm using the term "bug", but "insect" doesn't work either. :(

It shows up to the left of the filename in the tabs below the editor, always only on that one file I'm focusing on (by chance, I only do a lot of work on one file in each session).

There's no mouse-hover caption, or apparent documentation on it!  The insect seems to appear after 10-20 minutes or so.[image]

Edit: I promise I'll upload a screenshot as soon as it comes back. :)
Edit: Uploaded- the yellow hovering box is when I hover over the bug, which indicates there's no special description.

Comment: I would look into asking here in the pyscripter group. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/PyScripter

Comment: Without some kind of screenshot there is no way we can even begin to guess what this icon is.  Please edit your question to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I'm using PyScripter 2.5.3.0, the bug icon appears when my code has a syntax or formatting error.  For example, if PyScripter underlines some code in a window with a red wavy line, then the tab for that module will also have the bug icon.

Another example.  Create a new module, and type in the code:

```
x = for
```

Then press enter.  You will see the red wavy line and the bug icon appear by the modules tab.

If you then change your code to:

```
x = 2
```

Then press enter.  The red wavy line and bug icon both dissappear.